# How do I know if my high limit and low limit are set correctly on my aquastat?

Tags: heating, furnace, boiler

I have a boiler that is only providing heat for my heated water baseboard system with 4 zones.  I've always thought that the high limit on the aquastat was set too low. The temperature on the boiler reads around 145 when the heat cycle ends.  Most of what I've seen on heating sites recommends 180 or higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what type of system you are running. The lowest temperature possible sufficient to satisfy the heating load is recommended due to the fuel savings.

**To give you an idea**
[image]
**From a NHB service manual**

I personally wouldn't set anything contactable to more then 150ish°F.